# Merge rows into one row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I Have a table structure which similar to below

```
Create Table #Temp(Name varchar(10),Col1 int,Col2 int,Col3 int,Col4 int,Col5 int)
```

In this case table can have same name repeated but the other values to be different

So.

Sample values can be like

```
Insert Into #Temp
Values('ABC',1,0,0,1,1)
Insert Into #Temp
Values('ABC',1,0,1,1,0)
Insert Into #Temp
Values('ABC',1,0,1,1,0)
Insert Into #Temp
Values('DEF',0,0,0,1,0)
Insert Into #Temp
Values('DEF',1,0,1,1,1)
Insert Into #Temp
Values('DEF',1,1,0,1,1)
```

What I am trying to do here is select only one row for each name, but select the column with priority where it has value 1.

So the expected result in this case is

```
Name    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
ABC         1    0      1          1    1
DEF         1    1      1          1    1
```

I have achieved it by doing something like below, which works absolutely fine. But is there any proper(easy) way of doing this.

```
SELECT Name,
        (Select top 1 Col1
        from #Temp T 
        Where T.Name=M.Name
        Order By Col1 desc) as Col1,

        (Select top 1 Col2
        from #Temp T 
        Where T.Name=M.Name
        Order By Col2 desc) as Col2,

        (Select top 1 Col3
        from #Temp T 
        Where T.Name=M.Name
        Order By Col3 desc) as Col3,

        (Select top 1 Col4
        from #Temp T 
        Where T.Name=M.Name
        Order By Col4 desc)as Col4,

        (Select top 1 Col5
        from #Temp T 
        Where T.Name=M.Name
        Order By Col5 desc) as Col5
FROM #Temp M
Group By Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to use `MAX`:

```
SELECT  [Name],
        MAX(Col1) Col1,
        MAX(Col2) Col2,
        MAX(Col3) Col3,
        MAX(Col4) Col4,
        MAX(Col5) Col5
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Comment: If the data structure is diffrent for columns let say `varchar` and if i were to select data, can I use alternate way?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Well, it depends. Would your goal still be to choose `1`s over `0`s?, did anything else change in this new scenario?

Comment: I mean for example  ie. Column have date like 'A', 'B', 'C' etc and i need to give the priority for 'A' if exist and select other value if not

Comment: @huMptyduMpty In that case you would use `MIN` instead of `MAX`, but it would work

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  Max(Col1) as Col1, 
  Max(Col2) as Col2, 
  Max(Col3) as Col3, 
  Max(Col4) as Col4, 
  Max(Col5) as Col5
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: Cheers mate, Lamak was slightly earlier than you!